# AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate with SceneKit and AVDeviceCapture background

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, avcapturedevice

I'm trying to grab the CVPixelBuffer while using the camera video feed as a background to SceneKit.  Please note I cannot use ARKit for my project as I need the front + back camera and no world tracking overhead.  Even attempting the most basic example:

```
let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
self.scnScene.background.contents = captureDevice
```

results in the following error in iOS 11.2:

> [SceneKit] Error: Cannot get pixel buffer (CVPixelBufferRef)

Whenever this error pops up, the AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate stops being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was unable to simultaneously use the `AVCaptureDevice` as a background to SceneKit and grab its `CVPixelBuffer`, my solution was to render the sample buffer to a `MTLTexture` then apply that as a background to SceneKit.  See here as a starting point:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/displaying_an_ar_experience_with_metal